# Why can I login to mysql root with any password?

Tags: mysql

Can someone explain me why can I login as a root user with any password using:

`sudo mysql -u root -p`

(I can type anything in password prompt and it logs me in anyway)

My `/root/.my.cnf`

```
[client]
user=root
password=password123
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be because the "Unix socket authentication" plugin is enabled by default on your system. This appears to be the case on Debian 9 "Stretch" for instance.

On my system the `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf` configuration file states:

```
# * Unix socket authentication plugin is built-in since 10.0.22-6
#
# Needed so the root database user can authenticate without a password but
# only when running as the unix root user.
#
# Also available for other users if required.
# See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/unix_socket-authentication-plugin/
```